# Is there a name for this loading animation?

Tags: mobile-web, animation

I can notice this animation looks like an default pattern, because I've seen it at so many apps and websites.

I would like to know what's the name of it but I can't find any results.

[image]

Comment: Loading Animation?

Comment: Is there a name for this loading animation?

Comment: These are called Loading Dots. A simple Google search returned this. https://www.google.co.in/search?q=three+dot+loading+gif&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj78t2hoNzNAhVKOI8KHfAbB8EQsAQIHA&biw=1517&bih=741&dpr=0.9#imgrc=_

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They're called [Preloaders](https://www.google.co.uk/#q=preloader). I originally googled for ['Ajax loading animation'](https://www.google.co.uk/#q=ajax+loading+animation) to find that out. Plenty of results:

- [Ajaxload - Ajax loading gif generator](http://www.ajaxload.info/)
- [loading.io - Your SVG + GIF Ajax Loading Icons](http://loading.io/)
- [Preloaders.net - Loading GIF & APNG (AJAX loaders)

  generator](http://preloaders.net/)

Additionally, you might find this answer useful if you're looking for [How to create a “Please Wait, Loading…” animation using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1964839/how-can-i-create-a-please-wait-loading-animation-using-jquery).

Bonus: [Google Material Design Preloader](http://materializecss.com/preloader.html) for mobile design.

Answer (score 1):

It is just a different take on a wait spinner, which is called a [preloader](http://preloaders.net/) and is sometimes called a Loading animation.

Preloaders come in all shapes and sizes.